# web2py-skype integration

Tags: python, ssl, web2py, skype

I am getting an SSLError.

I want to integrate skype in my web2py application. I have skypekit downloaded from skype.com. But it gives the error:

```
SSLError:ssl read operation timed out
```

Here is a detailed stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "applications/filem/modules/skypekit_mod/ipc/python/skypekit.py", line 143, in run
self.connection._start()


File "applications/filem/modules/skypekit_mod/ipc/python/skypekit.py", line 521, in _start
if self._read_byte(1) == 'Z':



File "applications/filem/modules/skypekit_mod/ipc/python/skypekit.py", line 236, in _read_byte
read = self.socket.recv(4096)



 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ssl.py", line 215, in recv
return self.read(buflen)



File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ssl.py", line 136, in read
return self._sslobj.read(len)

SSLError: The read operation timed out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that implimenting SkypeKit on a server or through a browser is specifically restricted in the SkypeKit licence terms.

See : http://developer.skype.com/skypekit/legal/license
(login required)